# TNote Futures contract YTM vs yield on bought notes?

Tags: futures, yield, treasuries

I understand how to calculate the yield on a 10 yr TNote based on face, price & coupon.

I don’t understand why the yield (and price) on a futures contract about to expire is so different than the market yield (and price) if you buy a note instead.

For example March 21 10 Yr TNote contracts are about 131 which (I think) gives a yield of 2.48% but the notes auctioned last week had a yield of about 1.5%.

I understand the future is based on 6% coupon and e.g. last weeks auction had a coupon of 1.125% but I can’t see how this is reflected in the futures contract price.

If my data is correct(?) I don’t see why you wouldn’t buy the note, sell the future & pocket the difference?

Thanks for any help

Edit 1 = is the answer to be found in the conversion factor that will have the effect of changing the exercise price to something more recognisable per recent note sales?

Comment: Thanks Helin - I looked at this before my post but couldn’t see how I can find the conversion factor for example on the Mar 21 10 yr TNote... I’ve been using an online YTM calculator https://goodcalculators.com/bond-yield-to-maturity-calculator/ but of course it doesn’t know about the conversion factor...If the answer is the conversion factor then I guess I can practically ignore the calculation as my strategy will focus on note futures prices and a yield that does relate to market via some constant conversion...

Comment: try this excellent page https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/treasury-analytics.html

Comment: Perfect thank you very much!